# trying to access data from Model in view page. .Net Mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this class in my model

```
namespace Foreclosure.Models
{
public class foreclosureList
{
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfListings { get; set; }
}
public class RETS_ListingsModel
{

    public RETS_ListingsModel(){} // empty COnstructor

    public static IEnumerable<foreclosureList> getForeclosureList() // making an IEnumerable list to contain the forclosure data
    {
        SqlConnection myConn;
        SqlCommand myCmd;
        SqlDataReader myReader;

            System.Collections.ArrayList aforclosureList = new System.Collections.ArrayList(); // create an array to hold data, later it will be converted to the ienumerable list. 
            string mySql =
             "Select [Area], count (*) as numberListings from RETS_Listings_full" +
             " Where ForeclosureYN = 'Y'" +
             " AND Area <> ''" +
             " Group By Area";

            myConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
            myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand();
            myCmd.CommandText = mySql;
            myConn.Open();



            myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
               foreclosureList currentList = new foreclosureList(); // making an instance foreclosureList class and then adding the results from the query.
                currentList.Area = (string)myReader["Area"];
                currentList.NumberOfListings = (int)myReader["numberListings"];
                aforclosureList.Add(currentList); // adding the class object to the array
            }


            myReader.Close();
            myConn.Close();

            IEnumerable<foreclosureList> iforeclosureList = aforclosureList.Cast<foreclosureList>(); //converting the array back to the ienumerable list
            return iforeclosureList;
        }

    }


}
```

And on my View page I have

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Foreclosure.Models.foreclosureList>" %>
```

and then the code to dispaly the list is

```
   <ul>    
<% foreach ( var moo in Model)  
  {  %>
<li><%: moo.Area  %></li>  
   <% } %>         
</ul>
```

But I am getting an error :
CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Foreclosure.Models.foreclosureList' because 'Foreclosure.Models.foreclosureList' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Your view's Model is a ForeclosureList, not a List of ForeclosureLists.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this... 
So you are saying that I am trying to access a list of a list and not accessing just a list. 
how should I fix that?

Comment: Your view's model is stated as being a view of ONE foreclosureList, but in your view you're treating it as a list of this type. Change the inherited type to something like `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Foreclosure.Models.foreclosureList>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But I am getting an error : CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Foreclosure.Models.foreclosureList' because 'Foreclosure.Models.foreclosureList' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Try this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Foreclosure.Models.foreclosureList>>" %
```